# Example curses/ncurses Perl widget?

Tags: perl, ncurses, curses

I am trying to wrap my head around Curses/NCurses (still don't understand the difference) and perl, more exactly the `Curses::UI` modules, more exactly the Curses::UI::Widget package - see http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI/lib/Curses/UI/Widget.pm .

For understanding it, I would like to see some super-simple "Hello World" `Curses::UI::Widget` to start there.

There is a simple example in `Curses::UI::Widget` documentation, but that doesn't work, since it calls `$this->generic_focus` and it's undefined, and I have no idea what it should actually do.

Is there some actual tutorial for writing `Curses::UI` widgets, or at least some working examples?

***edit:*** To make myself clear: the basic text-editor from the documentation works from me, but now I would like to write my own widgets and I am not sure which functions to implement and how.

Mainly, I am not sure what should method `focus` do and if I have to implement the method `generic_focus` or not.

***edit 2:***

For example, in the linked documentation above, the function `generic_focus` is written as if it was implemented in `Curses::UI::Widget`, but it actually isn't implemented anywhere. What is going on exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Example borrowed from [this tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emdxi/Curses-UI-0.9609/lib/Curses/UI/Tutorial.pod)

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Curses::UI;
my $cui = new Curses::UI( -color_support => 1 );
my @menu = (
    { -label => 'File',
        -submenu => [
            { -label => 'Exit      ^Q', -value => \&exit_dialog  }
        ]
    },
);
sub exit_dialog()
{
    my $return = $cui->dialog(
        -message   => "Do you really want to quit?",
        -title     => "Are you sure???",
        -buttons   => ['yes', 'no'],

    );

    exit(0) if $return;
}
my $menu = $cui->add(
    'menu','Menubar',
    -menu => \@menu,
    -fg  => "blue",
);
my $win1 = $cui->add(
    'win1', 'Window',
    -border => 1,
    -y    => 1,
    -bfg  => 'red',
);
my $texteditor = $win1->add("text", "TextEditor",
    -text => "Here is some text\n"
    . "And some more");
$cui->set_binding(sub {$menu->focus()}, "\cX");
$cui->set_binding( \&exit_dialog , "\cQ");
$texteditor->focus();
$cui->mainloop();
```

---

The difference between curses and ncurses is that ncurses is an open source clone of curses. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517768/465183

Comment: Thanks, that works for me too, but now I would like to write my own widgets and I have no idea where to begin

Answer (score 2):

The simple examples from the documentation page work for me:

```
use Curses::UI;
my $cui = Curses::UI->new( -clear_on_exit => 1);
$cui->dialog("Hello, world!");
```