# GCC ld: can't find -lcurses

Tags: gcc, ld, curses

I'm trying to use make install, and I get error:

```
cannot find -lcurses
```

In my **/usr/lib/curses/** I have two files: **libcurses.so** and **libcurses.a**.

So I do have that library, gcc just doesn't see it. I've read almost everything I can find but still couldn't make this work.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is output:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcurses.so when searching for -lcurses
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:125: recipe for target 'samtools' failed
make: *** [samtools] Error 1
```

Note: I've read every similar topic on this website, so please, don't mark this as duplicate.

Comment: How do you call gcc? are you explicitly giving gcc the path for inclusion of lcurses?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982606/makefile-samtools-installation-failed You can see my makefile here. Basically I'm trying to install samtools but it fails because of this library.

Comment: As you yourself posted a question for the same error, this should be marked as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982606/makefile-samtools-installation-failed . Could be better served at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: gcc doesn't know about this `/usr/lib/curses` place. You need to tell it. Read the documentation about the `-L` option.

Comment: I read everything, I tried everything, please don't tell me read documentation I'm reading for last 5 hours.

Comment: Agreeing that `/usr/lib/curses` is odd - perhaps OP copied files from someplace.  By the way, posting to multiple forums confuses people.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, originally I taught the problem was with samtools which I'm trying to install.

Comment: @АлександарМакрагић What is the exact linker error message now that that you installed libncurses-devel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker says:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: \
skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcurses.so when searching for -lcurses
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses
```

You are performing a 64-bit build, but the the only `libcurses.so` the linker
can find is 32-bit, so it is skipped.

It is unclear from your several postings how this 32-bit `/usr/lib/libcurses.so` got
there. The [official latest openSUSE](http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.1/repo/oss/suse/x86_64/) 
curses runtime package is `libncurses5-5.9-53.4.x86_64.rpm`. The official latest developent package is `ncurses-devel-5.9-53.4.x86_64.rpm`.
If you install either of these packages, they do not place any 32-bit binaries under `/usr/lib`, so I surmise
that your `/usr/lib/libcurses.so` got there in some unorthodox way.

Delete this `/usr/lib/libcurses.so`. Install the `ncurses-devel` rpm from your distribution's package manager,
e.g.`zypper install ncurses-devel`. To make sure you have done it successfully, check that `/usr/lib64/libncurses.so` exists afterwards.
Then in your makefile change:

```
LIBCURSES=  -lcurses
```

to:

```
LIBCURSES=  -lncurses
```

You will find that this change is described in paragraph 3 of the `samtools` `INSTALL` file.

Comment: Changing from -lcurses to -lncurses fixed problem. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. To show that your problem is solved by this answer you can [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

You need a development library for ncurses installed, i.e., [`ncurses-devel`](https://software.opensuse.org/package/ncurses-devel) (for SuSE).

Without the *development* library, the shared libraries for ncurses are only present as *runtime* files.

The ncurses development package installs files or symbolic links to make these options work: `-lcurses`, `-lncurses` (since the former is standard).  It also installs the file to make `-lncursesw` link, but OP is not using that.

That message

```
skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcurses.so
```

makes it seem as if OP copied files from some other system rather than installing OpenSuSE packages.

The extra question in SuperUser ([GCC ld: can't find -lcurses](https://superuser.com/questions/1006863/gcc-ld-cant-find-lcurses/1006865#1006865)) gives more information, but not enough to see why the file `/usr/lib/libcurses.so` is incompatible.  It may be conflicting with the development package, however.

Comment: I just installed ncurses-devel. Unfortunately the problem is still there.