# Difference between the headers ncurses.h and curses.h

Tags: c++, c, ncurses, difference, curses

What is the difference between the headers `<ncurses.h>` and `<curses.h>` as variations for the curses library?

---

Why should I prefer

`#include <ncurses.h>`

Instead of

`#include <curses.h>`?

---

I have searched for the difference in my Linux distribution. In my implementation (Linux Ubuntu Pengolin), `<ncurses.h>` is an alias file for/to the header file of `<curses.h>`. So there is no difference.

But why is than the separation with two names?

---

Unfortunately the answers to this question [What's the difference between -lcurses and -lncurses when compiling C using ncurses lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517756/whats-the-difference-between-lcurses-and-lncurses-when-compiling-c-using-ncur) do not solve my concerns as they are more focused on the adding of the respective flags when invoking the compiler and do not explain about the difference in general.

Comment: `curses.h` is more portable. `ncurses.h` is not going to be available on all systems.

Comment: Curses is the name of the original library from SystemV.
NCurses is an open source implementation of the library, with the same API.

Every implementation will provide their specific header, like ncurses.h, pcurses.h, and they will provide a symbolic link of curses.h to their specific header, so that you dont have to care which implementation you have.

Comment: If you want NCurses implementation of the curses library specifically, and you are shure the implementation will be available at the target computer, you can use ncurses.h.

If you just want some implementation of the curses API, use the curses.h, which may or may not be implemented by NCurses or some other implementation of the library.

Answer (score 4):

All implementations of X/Open Curses provide a "curses.h".  ncurses provides this via a symbolic link to its own implementation "ncurses.h", making it possible to select that header file if there is another implementation installed, e.g., on Solaris.

If you were configuring ncurses (to build it), the [`INSTALL`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/0626a47890ce073c00ee521eb1bbe2b707b3e1e0/INSTALL#L400) file explains it in the context of one of the configure options:

```
--disable-overwrite
    If you are installing ncurses on a system which contains another
    development version of curses, or which could be confused by the loader
    for another version, we recommend that you leave out the link to
    -lcurses.  The ncurses library is always available as -lncurses.
    Disabling overwrite also causes the ncurses header files to be
    installed into a subdirectory, e.g., /usr/local/include/ncurses,
    rather than the include directory.  This makes it simpler to avoid
    compile-time conflicts with other versions of curses.h

    Putting the header files into a subdirectory assumes that applications
    will follow the (standard) practice of including the headers with
    reference to the subdirectory name.  For instance, the normal ncurses
    header would be included using

        #include <ncurses/curses.h>
        #include <ncurses/term.h>

    while the ncursesw headers would be found this way:

        #include <ncursesw/curses.h>
        #include <ncursesw/term.h>

    In either case (with or without the --disable-overwrite option),
    almost all applications are designed to include a related set of
    curses header files from the same directory.

    Manipulating the --includedir configure option to put header files
    directly in a subdirectory of the normal include-directory defeats
    this, and breaks builds of portable applications.  Likewise, putting
    some headers in /usr/include, and others in a subdirectory is a good
    way to break builds.

    When configured with --disable-overwrite, the installed header files'
    embedded #include's are adjusted to use the same style of includes
    noted above.  In particular, the unctrl.h header is included from
    curses.h, which means that a makefile which tells the compiler to
    include directly from the subdirectory will fail to compile correctly.
    Without some special effort, it will either fail to compile at all,
    or the compiler may find a different unctrl.h file.
```