# How to use dialog.h in a c program

Tags: c, linux, dialog, ncurses, curses

I am trying to use `dialog.h`in my C program. For this I looked up the manual (`man 3 dialog`) and used the example code, which they have provided. This is how my C program look like (it is called `main.c`):

```c
#include <dialog.h>

int main(void)
{
  int status;
  init_dialog(stdin, stdout);
  status = dialog_yesno(
    "Hello, in dialog-format",
    "Hello World!",
    0, 0);
  end_dialog();
  return status;
}
```

After research I figured out, that the `dialog` program is based on `ncurses`. So I have installed both libraries, which contains the required header files.

I am working on Debian so:
`apt install dialog libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev`

In the next step I have called the compiler, and I have also linked the libraries: `gcc main.c -ldialog -lncurses`

---

But compiling did not succeed.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(util.o): In function `dlg_auto_size':
(.text+0x1a06): undefined reference to `sqrt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(trace.o): In function `dlg_trace_win':
(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to `win_wch'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(trace.o): In function `dlg_trace_win':
(.text+0x2ab): undefined reference to `wunctrl'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(arrows.o): In function `dlg_draw_arrows2':
(.text+0x2c4): undefined reference to `_nc_wacs'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(arrows.o): In function `dlg_draw_arrows2':
(.text+0x2d6): undefined reference to `wadd_wch'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(arrows.o): In function `dlg_draw_arrows2':
(.text+0x43c): undefined reference to `_nc_wacs'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(arrows.o): In function `dlg_draw_arrows2':
(.text+0x44e): undefined reference to `wadd_wch'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(arrows.o): In function `dlg_draw_scrollbar':
(.text+0x878): undefined reference to `_nc_wacs'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(arrows.o): In function `dlg_draw_scrollbar':
(.text+0x88f): undefined reference to `wvline_set'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(inputstr.o): In function `dlg_index_columns':
(.text+0x932): undefined reference to `setcchar'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(inputstr.o): In function `dlg_index_columns':
(.text+0x93c): undefined reference to `wunctrl'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdialog.a(ui_getc.o): In function `dlg_getc':
(.text+0x603): undefined reference to `wget_wch'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After research I found out that the missing references to some functions like `win_wch`, `wunctrl`, etc. are all defined in `curses.h`.

Regarding to this post ([What's the difference between -lcurses and -lncurses when compiling C using ncurses lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517756/whats-the-difference-between-lcurses-and-lncurses-when-compiling-c-using-ncur)) `ncurses` and `curses` are the same due `curses` is linked to `ncurses`.

But anyway, I have tried to compile with the `curses` library too: `gcc main.c -lcurses -lncurses -ldialog`. But it did not work either.

What am I missing? Why did compiling fail?

Comment: Since libdialog is based on libncurses, try putting `-ldialog` *before* the other library lines.  This used to be a thing, perhaps modern linkers don't have this issue, but worth a try.

Comment: Good to know. But unfortunately it does not work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some testing on a Debian-based system (a Beaglebone), and this was not an obvious fix.  Turns out there are multiple versions of the ncurses library, and the dialog library was built with *one* of them, just not the one you were using.

The way you're supposed to figure this out is with the `dialog-config` command, which has options to show which CFLAGS or libraries you need on the compile line (or in the makefile), but I didn't find it on my system, so I looked at `/usr/include/dlg_config.h` for some clues:

```
...
#define DLG_HAVE_LIBINTL_H 1
#define DLG_HAVE_LIBNCURSESW 1   <---
#define DLG_HAVE_LIMITS_H 1
```

Hmmm, this suggests it needs `-lncursesw` instead of `-lncurses`, so we see this compile:

```
$ gcc dlg.c -ldialog -lncursesw
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdialog.a(util.o): in function `dlg_auto_size':
(.text+0x13d2): undefined reference to `sqrt'
```

Ok, so a lot closer: `sqrt()` is in the math library, so adding `-lm` gets it over the goal line:

```
$ gcc dlg.c -ldialog -lncursesw -lm
```

It seems that `ncursesw` is a wide-character version that works with an international character set, which was new to me.

EDIT: Elaborating on the "dialog-config" stuff: The way you're supposed to do this is documented in the `dialog(3)` manual page:

```
gcc $(dialog-config --cflags) file ... $(dialog-config --libs)
```

The idea is that a package can publish what it needs to build in a command, so in this case I imagine that `dialog-config --cflags` might not output anything, but `dialog-config --libs` would output `-ldialog -lncursesw -lm`, so you could embed this in your makefile and have it do the right thing.

This paradigm is common, and on my system I see (for example) `/usr/bin/python-config` that shows how it was built on this machine:

```
$ python-config --cflags
-I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/python2.7
-fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g
-fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-RT6aMn/python2.7-2.7.16=.
-fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG
-g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

$ python-config --libs
-lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
```

If you were trying to build some kind of Python plugin, guessing the above parameters would be a real challenge.

Comment: Thanks, I would never have figured this out on my own.